# Shofar bent to the right

Tags: shofar

There is a custom to blow the shofar from the right side of the mouth. 585/6; Rama 585/2 in name of Minhagim; Shlah brought in M”A 585/4; Kaf Hachaim 585/29
Is there a benefit of having a shofar that is bent specifically to the right hand side?
If so, is it to the right of the shofar blower or right side of the animal that it came from?

Comment: Re - "right side of the animal that it came from" - 1) Why would this be important or critical? 2) If you bought a shofar from a store, I would be surprised if the merchant had any clue about this.  There is a *machloket* as to whether one may use a twisted shofar, but I am quite certain that it is allowed though not preferred.

Comment: @DanF I’m not sure what you mean by a twisted shofar. A bent shofar is clearly brought down as preferred as Gd desires a bent heart etc

Comment: If you have seen a "Yemenite" shofar, it is twisted. It is one of a number of twisted shofarot. Several animals have twisted horns. See https://shofarsogreat.com/Home.html as an example.